# Right column height equal to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two columns and I want to resize the height of the right column to the same height of the `left`. The `right` column is cut from buttom.

Here some screenshots to show my problem:

[image]

[image]

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKKxy/2/)

Comment: Please post your code and create a fiddle of your problem on jsfiddle.net or a similar site.

Comment: @Mihran isn't my answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = document.getElementById("leftcolumn").offsetHeight; // you can change leftcolumn here with your left column id
document.getElementById("rightcolumn").style.height = s+"px"; // you can change rightcolumn here with your right column id
```

Comment: what is the problem in code? who downvoted? tell me so, i can learn from my mistake :)

Comment: and i want that man who downvoted my answer! :) can you bring him here :P

Comment: what i have to do with this link @Mihran I have seen that its working! and i was also sure that i was answering correct!

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib I think the question was understood by downvoter as pure css/html

Comment: @EL man see your user id of stackexchange.com : user:1571000 that's pretty good!

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib terrific row of zeros? =)

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib odd is better for superstition believers =)